# Why am I cutting off heads?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have several hours of gameplay under my belt and have enjoyed using the finishing move when I kill people. However, instead of running people through to finish them off, my character has started cutting off their heads. Does anyone know if this is a reflection on my characters personality (good/evil), or could it be because I recently got to level 25?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both the One-handed and Two-handed skill trees each have a perk which gives a chance to decapitate enemies on a power attack. For One-handed its called 'Savage Strike' and for Two-handed its called 'Devastating Blow'. Did you by any chance take either of these perks recently? This could explain why you suddenly started decapitating enemies.

And no, it is not a reflection on your characters personality (good/evil). As far as I know(and someone correct me if I am wrong) there is no good/evil stat system in Skyrim. It does track your crime but that in itself cannot be considered as the same as a good/evil morality system.

For more info:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:One-handed

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Two-handed

Comment: I did get one of those. That'll teach me to pay more attention to my levelling.

Comment: Its a pretty cool animation actually, but it does get tiring after seeing it a few 100 times.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to swing off heads with my Daedric greatsword as soon as I got Rahgot's Mask.